# Excel saving CSV with tabs

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a colleague using Excel 2007 on XP, and every time she saves her workbook as a .csv file, she is getting tabs for delimiters. Any idea what is happening, and how we can get commas instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

choose ms-dos csv as the file type!

Comment: Bang on. Terribly confusing why the Comma Separated Values format wasn't saving with commas :)

Answer (score 2):

http://mavericksquest.blogspot.com/2011/06/excel-to-custom-character-delimited.html

if your default delimeter changed you can set it back there (in windows: Control Panel > Regional and Language Settings > Customize > Set List Separator field to ,)
now you can save as csv through excel (saveas > other formats > csv)